# How often to redraw a javascript canvas to have a smooth animation effect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I am using React and javascript, I have a canvas with a 'player' square and an 'enemy' square. The player position is determined by the mouse coordinates, while I want the 'enemy' to have a pre determined path.

```
const Canvas = props => {   

        useEffect( () => {
            setEnemy1X(enemy1X+1);
                setEnemy1Y(enemy1Y+1);
        },[tempGame])
        
        useEffect(() =>{
            
            //canvas variables
            const canvas = canvasRef.current
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d')          
            canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width
            canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height
            setCanvasWidth(canvas.width);
            setCanvasHeight(canvas.height);
            
            var player1 = { x: playerX, y: playerY, draggable: gameStatus }
            var enemy1 = { x: enemy1X, y: enemy1Y, width: enemy3Width, height: enemy4Height}

// this function is running forever 
            const drawFun = () => {

                context.clearRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)

                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = '#00f4cc'
                context.fillRect(player1.x, player1.y, playerWidth, playerHeight)

                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = 'red'
                context.fillRect(enemy1.x, enemy1.y, enemy1Width, enemy1Height)
requestAnimationFrame(drawFun);
            }
            drawFun();


//on mouse move
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

                e.preventDefault();
                
                var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                var x = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
                var y = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.

 //if game is running
                if( gameStatus ){               

                    setPlayerX(x - playerWidth/2);
                    setPlayerY(y - playerHeight/2);
```

[image]

The issue I am having right now is I am trying to update the X and Y coordinates of the red square by incrementing the values by 1 using `setEnemy1X(enemy1X+1) and setEnemy1Y(enemy1Y+1)` if I place this under mousemove event, the animation looks smooth and slow. If i try updating the coordinates within `drawFun` or the `UseEffect` at the beginning, the whole canvas flickers as if it has to be redrawn to fast.

To be more clear, I am trying to have that red square move diagonally across the screen by updating the X and Y coordinates. If I do this via a mousemove event, the animation looks nice and smooth, anywhere else I try to update the animation the whole canvas starts flickering because of what I'm assuming is the canvas being updated to many times a second. I tried to include everything I think is relevant to the question, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually updates are done in `requestAnimationFrame` which uses monitor refresh rate (usually 60 times a second or more, epending on your monitor it can even be 180 times per second).

Comment: That flickering is rather not related to how many times the canvas updates

Comment: is there to specify a refresh rate? I tried updating the coordinates inside my ```drawFun``` which uses ```requestAnimationFrame``` but I encountered the same issue as I am having with using a seperate ```UseEffect``` , the issue being the canvas flickers

Comment: I would rather guess that the flickering is related to the fact that you store enemy position in state which causes the component to rerender.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yep you were right, using enemy1.x in my case is what I should be using instead of updating the state. Thanks!